# RHEL 5.5 - Operating System Installation

Tags: linux, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

Is it possible to customize versions of packages like "binutils , Glibc , libstd .." while installing the operating system??

Answer (score 0):

Not while installing no. During the installation process you are installing packages from rpms. There is no way of editing the contents of the rpm during the installation process. Your best bet would be to install a minimal system, log in, make the changes you want to the various sources and then install the modified packages.